# Position 3 buttons to left, center, and right on same row

Tags: python, tkinter

I did this but buttons are not on same row:

```py
button_frame = tk.Frame()
button_frame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

x = tk.Button(button_frame, text = 'x')
x.pack(side = 'left', ipadx = 3, ipady = 1)


y= tk.Button(button_frame, text = 'y')
y.pack(side = 'top', ipadx = 3, ipady = 1)


z= tk.Button(button_frame, text = 'z')
z.pack(side = 'right', ipadx = 3, ipady = 1)
```

I also tried to position every button with `side = 'left'` + `padx = (0, number)` but it works on only my own screen resolution.

Comment: Use `grid()` instead of `pack()`.

Comment: I could do `widget.grid(row = 0, column = previouscolumnnumber + 1)` which is not what I mean

Comment: @yg213 Could you elaborate more on exactly what output you expect?

Comment: Actually, you _can_ use grid. You just need to use `button_frame.rowconfigure()` and `button_frame.columnconfigure()` and `grid()`'s `sticky` argument to make sure that things are positioned correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want using `.pack()`, but the order of packing the buttons matters:

```py
x = tk.Button(button_frame, text='x')
y = tk.Button(button_frame, text='y')
z = tk.Button(button_frame, text='z')

# pack left and right first
x.pack(side='left')
z.pack(side='right')
# then pack top
y.pack(side='top')
```

However I would suggest to use `grid()` instead:

```py
x = tk.Button(button_frame, text='x')
y = tk.Button(button_frame, text='y')
z = tk.Button(button_frame, text='z')

button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
x.grid(row=0, column=0)
y.grid(row=0, column=1)
z.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This script using grid() is one way to place the three buttons on one row with buttons anchored left, center, and right. The self.columnconfigure statements for columns 0 and 2 are not necessary for the proportional resizing, but may be useful for additional widget layout methods.

Using sticky in combination with columnspan and columnconfigure controls where the buttons are positioned in relation to the button_frame as the window resizes.

```
import tkinter as tk


class CenterButtons(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.grid()

    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    self.xyz_buttons()

    @staticmethod
    def xyz_buttons():
        """Keep buttons evenly spaced with window resizing."""

        button_frame = tk.Frame()
        button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.EW)

        button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        x = tk.Button(button_frame, text='x')
        y = tk.Button(button_frame, text='y')
        z = tk.Button(button_frame, text='z')

        x.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=3, padx=3, sticky=tk.W)
        y.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=3, padx=3)
        z.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=3, padx=3, sticky=tk.E)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CenterButtons()
    app.minsize(125, 40)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP wanted. They seem to want `x` to be on the left, `y` to be centered in the middle, and `z` to be on the right, presumably when the window resizes as well. This code doesn't do that; the buttons stay huddled in the corner when the window is resized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The code is updated to address these concerns.  As the window expands, x stays on the left, y stays centered, and z stays on the right.